# Which XML structure should I choose?

Tags: xml, oracle, solr, xml-parsing, xsd

I am using Oracle XML DB to manage profiles of my clients. I want to make the profile extensible and search engine friendly(I plan to use Apache Solr for searching). I currently conceived two different structures:

```
<profile>
<picture>
</picture>
<am>
    <sex>male</sex>
    <born_on>02/20/1989</born_on>
    <job>programmer</job>
</am>
<contact_information>
    <address>somewhere</address>
    <zip_code>somenumber</zip_code>
    <cellphone>somenumber</cellphone>
</contact_information>
<famliy>
    <parents>
        <father></father>
        <mother></mother>
    </parents>
</famliy>
<study_at>
</study_at>
<work_at>
</work_at>
<live_at>
</live_at>
<like>
</like>
    ....
```

the second type is

```
<profile>
    <list name="am">
        <item name="sex">male</item>
        <item name="job">programmer</item>
    </list>
    <list name="study at">
        <item>someschool</item>
        <item>someschool</item>
    </list>
    ....
 </profile>
```

The first one can be easily parsed by XPath while the second can have white space and more attributes. Which one is better? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either of it to create XML, the difference will be coming up when you parse dis two types of xml. But i and xml format prefers Second type as XPath gives us flexibility to parse XML and get values of the element and also for the element's attribute. So go ahead for SECOND Type.

Read this for extra: [XPATH](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_examples.asp)

Njoy!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think there will be no difference. Choose the one your personally prefer. You will have to use the ImportDataHandler with a XSL to transform the data anyway.

edit: DataImportHandler I´m sorry...